# PostgreSQL, getting min and max date from text column

Tags: postgresql

I have such situation in table:

```
1   01.02.2011
2   05.01.2011
3   06.03.2012
4   07.08.2011
5   04.03.2013
6   06.08.2011
7   
8   02.02.2013
9   04.06.2010
10  10.10.2012
11  04.04.2012
```

where first column is id (INT) and second column is TEXT in which may be written date in format 'dd.mm.yyyy'.

I would like to get:
1) lowest entered date in whole table and highest entered date in whole table.
2) lowest entered date in year 2012 and highest entered date in year 2012.

Lowest and highest date in year may be a same (like for year 2010) or field may be empty (like in row 7).

I am tying to use TO_TIMESTAMP but unsuccessfully.
Example:

```
SELECT (TO_TIMESTAMP(mydatetxt, 'DD.MM.YYYY'))   
FROM " & myTable & "   
ORDER BY (TO_TIMESTAMP(mydatetxt, 'DD.MM.YYYY')) ASC LIMIT 1
```

Also with BETWEEN I don't get wanted result.

How to write those two queries?

SOLUTION:
Thanks for all suggestions.
Igor's solution is most suitable and simple enough for me.

```
Dim sqlText As String = "SELECT min(to_date(nullif(mydate,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY')) FROM " & mytable
cmd1 = New NpgsqlCommand(sqlText, conn)
min = CDate(cmd1.ExecuteScalar())
If Not IsDate(min) Then
    min = CType(CDate("01.01." & myyear) & " 00:00:00", Date)
End If
fromdate = CType(CDate(min), Date)

sqlText = "SELECT max(to_date(mydate, 'DD.MM.YYYY')) FROM " & mytable
cmd1 = New NpgsqlCommand(sqlText, conn)
max = CDate(cmd1.ExecuteScalar())
If Not IsDate(max) Then
    max = CType(CDate("31.12." & myyear) & " 23:59:59.9999", Date)
End If
todate = CType(CDate(max), Date)
```

Comment: Can you show your queries and tell why they do not work?

Comment: I am update question with example query for getting minimal date on your request. I don't know why my queries don't work. If I would know then help would not be needed.

Comment: How does the query `don't work`? Any error messages? Wrong results? Something else?

Comment: I am using this through NET and npgsql adapter, so on executescalar I get error message: 'Specified cast is not valid'. Maybe becuse I have only dat but not time for converting to timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT max(to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY')),
       min(to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
FROM table_name;

SELECT max(to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY')),
       min(to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
FROM table_name
WHERE date_part('year',to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY')) = 2012;
```

Comment: That one is most simple and highly usable for my case. Thanks a lot.