# PostgreSQL, count of rows between min and max dates

Tags: postgresql

I am getting min and max dates from text column with query which good people helped me to get [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183744/postgresql-getting-min-and-max-date-from-text-column) like this :

```
SELECT max(to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY')),
min(to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
FROM table_name;
```

How can I get COUNT of all matched rows between and including min and max dates (written in text column)?

Comment: This schema makes me want to cry. A really good start would be to prepare, adapt your queries, and when you're ready do an `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN mydatetext TYPE date USING (to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY'))` to turn this into a real date column you can work with sanely.

Comment: actually `COUNT of all matched rows between and including min and max dates` is just count(*) :)

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is:

```
SELECT count(*), max(to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY')), min(to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY')) 
  FROM table_name;
```

Or maybe I misunderstood.  Really, you should, if at all possible, move the date field to a date type.  If you have to handle garbage input, use a view and an update trigger to do that.