# PostgreSQL, min, max and count of dates in range

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, count, date-range

This question is based of two previous [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183744/postgresql-getting-min-and-max-date-from-text-column) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18185576/postgresql-count-of-rows-between-min-and-max-dates).

I am trying very hard to get those two queries:

```
SELECT min(to_date(nullif(mydatetext,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY')) AS dmin,
       max(to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY')) AS dmax
FROM mytable
```

and

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM mytable
WHERE
to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''))  'ERROR HERE
BETWEEN 
max(to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
AND
min(to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''), 'DD.MM.YYYY'))
```

in single one so I can read result as minimal date, maximal date, count of dates between and including min and max dates.
But here are few problems.

Second query don't work as expected or don't work at all so have to be improved.
If those two queries can be writen in single query (?) can I use dmin and dmax variables from first part as variables in second part?
Like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM mytable
WHERE
to_date(nullif(mydatetxt,''))  'ERROR HERE
BETWEEN 
dmin
AND
dmax
```

Please help to solve this situation finally.

Workable code:

```
Using cmd As New NpgsqlCommand("SELECT my_id, mydate FROM " & mytable, conn)
Using dr As NpgsqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()
        mydate = CStr(dr(1))

        If IsDate(mydate) Then
            Dim dat As Date = CDate(mydate.Substring(6, 4) & "/" & mydate.Substring(3, 2) & "/" & mydate.Substring(0, 2))
            If dat < mindate Or mindate = Nothing Then
                mindate = dat
            End If

            If dat > maxddate Or maxdate = Nothing Then
                maxdate = dat
            End If

            count += 1
        End If
    End While
End Using
End Using
```

SOLUTION:
And this is finally very fast, improved version which Ervin kindly give:

```
        Using cmd As New NpgsqlCommand( _
             "WITH base AS (" & _
             "  SELECT TO_DATE(datum, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS the_date " & _
             "  FROM " & myKalkTable & " " & _
             "  WHERE datum <> '') " & _
             "  SELECT MIN(the_date) AS dmin, " & _
             "         MAX(the_date) AS dmax, " & _
             "         COUNT(*) AS ct_incl, " & _
             "  (SELECT COUNT(*) " & _
             "         FROM base b1 " & _
             "         WHERE(b1.the_date < max(b.the_date)) " & _
             "         AND b1.the_date > min(b.the_date)) " & _
             "         AS ct_excl " & _
             "         FROM base b", conn)

            Using dr As NpgsqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While dr.Read()
                    mindate = CType(CDate(CStr(dr(0))), Date)
                    maxdate = CType(CDate(CStr(dr(1))), Date)
                    count = CInt(dr(2))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
```

Comment: This is your third question in this "thread" and your version of Postgres as well as the table definition are still your secret. Please provide both. Would also answer the question whether `mydatetext`is a typo or a different column. Seems like you need to think about your table layout. Storing `dates` as `text` is a serious mistake.

Comment: Simple task but I can't get wanted result whole day. This thread is different in mean that contain result of both previous ones which are referred in question. 'mydatetext' is column name choosen for this example but it is of type 'text' that's why we do 'to_date' conversion. I can't give more real code because 1) I work in NET/npgsql and real codes are too complex and mostly not relevant for solving this issue. Data is 'as is' and I can't change it now. Sorry.

Comment: What do you get for `SELECT version()`?

Comment: I get: "PostgreSQL 9.1.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 32-bit". I update question with code which I use now and which work OK but I search for solution without looping.

Comment: BTW: your "workable code" does not work. Smells like LEGO, too.

Comment: What LEGO? What smells? My workable code work exactly as expected. It gives me mindate, maxdate form column and number of rows between and including those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given this table (like you should have provided):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl (
   id        int PRIMARY KEY
  ,mydatetxt text
 );

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1, '01.02.2011')
 ,(2, '05.01.2011')
 ,(3, '06.03.2012')
 ,(4, '07.08.2011')
 ,(5, '04.03.2013')
 ,(6, '06.08.2011')
 ,(7, '')             -- empty string
 ,(8, '02.02.2013')
 ,(9, '04.06.2010')
 ,(10, '10.10.2012')
 ,(11, '04.04.2012')
 ,(12, NULL)          -- NULL
 ,(13, '04.03.2013'); -- min date a 2nd time
```

The query should produce what you describe:

> result as minimal date, maximal date, count of dates between and including min and max dates

```
WITH base AS (
   SELECT to_date(mydatetxt, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AS the_date
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  mydatetxt <> ''  -- excludes NULL and ''
   )
SELECT min(the_date) AS dmin
      ,max(the_date) AS dmax
      ,count(*) AS ct_incl
      ,(SELECT count(*)
        FROM   base b1
        WHERE  b1.the_date < max(b.the_date)
        AND    b1.the_date > min(b.the_date)
       ) AS ct_excl
FROM   base b
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/968a2/1)

[CTEs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) require Postgres 8.4 or later.
Consider to [upgrade to the latest point release](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) of 9.1, which is currently **9.1.9**.